# cassandra, is there a way of "moving" tombstoned (old) data to an other sstable on a different folder?

Tags: cassandra

Typically more recent data are more important for most applications. What I would like to do is store all the data for a very long time but have more recent data (say 500GB of them) in an SSD and the older data in normal 7200rpm hard disks which are cheap and I can get 3TB for £100. Is there a way to do that with cassandra? I.e. to TTL the data to expire after a year but instead of deleting them actually to move them in an sstable on a different folder (which can be linked to a different hard disk)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Archive and store the data that are more than an year old in a separate column family. Have that column family storage pointed to a HDD in data file directories portion of cassandra.yaml(Using symlinks- Check the cassandra docs for this if you have any doubts).

Set the TTL for the column family residing on SSD. You have to make the assumption of archival time logics based on your application intensity.